# Does oath of citizenship make citizens inequal?

Tags: immigration

In many countries, such as Germany, Russia, South Africa, and the US, there is a so-called [oath of citizenship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_citizenship), which is essentially some specific words that a person who becomes a citizen of the country must say before obtaining citizenship.

I wonder if this can be considered inequality? Think of it for a moment: the people who were born citizens of the country never had to take an oath. Not when they learned to speak, not after turning the age of majority. These people are allowed to be citizens of the country without making any political statements. And it feels like this is not fair: why speaking specific words can be required from only some of the citizens?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we generally don't answer questions which can only be answered with personal opinions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's expected from people who are naturalized citizens because they are, prior to the naturalization, actually foreigners, and hence an oath is used to ensure loyalty and love for whatever country they wish to become citizens of.

It's not expected from natural-born citizens because, given that the country wherein they reside is the only they've ever known, one can reasonably expect them to be loyal to the country without an oath. That said, an argument can be made that natural-born citizens should be expected to take an oath once they reach the age of majority.

Comment: Reminds me of the Starship Troopers movie (not the book) and how no one is a citizen unless they are willing to do something to become a citizen.  I used to think that would make for a better society, not so sure now.